# Does DolphinDB support retention policy?

Tags: dolphindb, retention

In InfluxDB I can create a two-hour retention policy like this:

```
> CREATE RETENTION POLICY "two_hours" ON "food_data" DURATION 2h REPLICATION 1 DEFAULT
```

In VictoriaMetrics, retention is configured with -retentionPeriod command-line flag. For instance, `-retentionPeriod=3` means that the data will be stored for 3 months and then deleted.

Is there an equivalent function in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dolphindb supports setting retention policies.
You can call the function [setRetentionPolicy](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/setRetentionPolicy.html) to set .